# Import multiple CSV files, get variable names and import filename to new variable

Tags: r, csv, import

Trying to import multiple CSV files in a folder into R.
The CSV files all have the same structure, a first line to skip and then a second line are the variable names to import - after that the data starts.
I'd like to import all CSV files in one folder, get the variable names from the second line of the first file (and then subsequently skip all lines 1+2 from the following CSV files) and additionally add another column "ID" with the filename of the CSV file.

Currently I have:
(It skips the first two lines of all files and sets variables manually, but I would like to get them from line 2 automatically)

```
setwd("c:/datafolder/")
filenames <- Sys.glob("*.csv")
allData <- lapply(filenames, function(.file){

  dat<-read.csv(.file, header=F,skip=2)
  names(dat)<-c("variablename1",
                "variablename2",
                "variablename3"
  )

  dat$id<-as.character(.file)
  dat
})
combined_data <- do.call(rbind, allData)
```

Comment: Could you show what you have already tried?

Comment: If you also showed an example of expected input and output, it would be easier to understand your question.

Comment: edited the post with my current code

Answer (score 0):

I'll give this one a try:

```
inputfilename <- "filename"
df <- read.csv(inputfilename, header = F, stringsAsFactors = F, sep = ";")
df
       V1      V2      V3
1 bad row bad row bad row
2    Name     Age  Gender
3    John      12       M
4    Jane      20       F
names(df) <- df[2,]
df <- df[-c(1:2),]
df
  Name Age Gender
3 John  12      M
4 Jane  20      F
df$ID <- inputfilename
df <- df[,c(4,1:3)]
df
  ID        Name  Age     Gender
3  filename John  12      M
4  filename Jane  20      F
```

After this you could just combine the different dataframes into 1.

Comment: thanks! But this just works for one file, I cannot figure out how to use this with multiple files and get the variable names one file.

Comment: Are the names of all the files similar? Like filename1, filename2 etc?

Comment: I just want to import *.csv from one folder, file names are constructed as "ID".csv

Comment: Then you just need to add `filenames <- list.files()

for(i in 1:length(filenames)) {
  inputfilename <- filenames[i]`